# Solve $\left(3x^2y-xy\right)dx+\left(2x^3y^2+x^3y^4\right)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

$\left(3x^2y-xy\right)dx+\left(2x^3y^2+x^3y^4\right)dy=0$

I'm trying to solve this first-order differential equation. I know it's not an exact equation so I'm trying to use the method taught in class to solve it. I get stuck trying to do the integrating factor. Below is what I have:

$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(M\right)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(3x^2y-xy\right) = 6xy-y$

$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial y}\left(N\right)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(2x^3y^2+x^3y^4\right)dy = 4x^3y+4x^3y^3$

And since $\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(N\right)\neq\frac{\partial }{\partial \:x}\left(M\right)$, have that it is not exact.

So we apply the formula to get an integrating factor:
$\xi =\frac{\left(\:\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)}{N}$ to get a function $\xi(x)$, or the formula $\xi =\frac{\left(\:\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)}{-M}\:$ to get a function $\xi(y)$.

We use $\xi$ to get an integrating factor $\mu(x)=e^{\int \:\xi(x) dx}$ or $\mu(y)=e^{\int \:\xi(x) dy}$.

Now, when I apply either one of the formulas for $\xi$, I always get a result dependent on both $x$ and $y$, so I'm unable to get the integrating factor.

Is there supposed to be a simpler way to solve this? I'm using this method because it's what was taught in class, but is there another simple way to solve this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: This isn't an equation for integrating factors. That's for the form $f'(x) + a(x) f(x) = b(x)$. What you have here is separable. Isolate $f(x)dx = g(y)dy$ and integrate both sides.

Comment: @kevinkayaks why is it separable? I thought it wasn't separable, so I tried to do this

Comment: $(3x^2-x)y dx = -(2y^2 + y^4)x^3 dy$ - can you finish separating from here?

Comment: What kevin points out is the very first you must try to check in this kind of equations. Seperable ODE are, in general, easier to solve that non separable ones. And btw: to try exactness you must do $\;M_y\,,\,\,N_x\;$ , and not the other way around.

Comment: @kevinkayaks thank you!

Comment: @DonAntonio Makes sense now, thank you!

Comment: A further note: integrating factors are based on using the product rule in reverse. We have $f'(x) + a(x) f(x) = \exp(-\int^x a(x')dx')\frac{d}{dx}\big[ \exp(\int^x a(x')dx') f(x)\big]$. If you view it like this, it's actually very simple, for when you get to using them in the near future. They allow you convert certain equations into separable ones.

Comment: @kevinkayaks I solved it as separable, by integrating it. And I get the result $y^2+1/4(y^4)+k = -3ln|x|-1/x$, for constant $k$. So for the general solution, $y$ can't be isolated alone as a function of $x$. Does this matter?

Comment: Nope, it just means the solution is a transcendental equation. You can still use such a solution to get the $y$ (s) corresponding to a given $x$ to any desired accuracy. But differentiate (with implicit differentiation) and check that you get your original equation back.

Comment: However, what you sent can be solved for $y$. It is a quadratic equation in $y^2$. For example, you can do something like $y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{-4\pm \sqrt{16-4(12 \log|x| -4/x)}}{2}} $. This suggests there would be four solutions. (check carefully, done very loosely)

Comment: @kevinkayaks okay, thank you for all the help!

Comment: Why the tag "partial differential equation"? I see an ODE but no PDE in your question. Downvote -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(3x^2y-xy\right)dx+\left(2x^3y^2+x^3y^4\right)dy=0$$
$$xy\Big(\left(3x-1\right)dx+x^2y\left(2+y^2\right)dy\Big)=0$$
First trivial solution :
$$y(x)=0$$
Second trivial solution :
$$x(y)=0$$
Remaining equation :
$$\left(3x-1\right)dx+x^2y\left(2+y^2\right)dy=0$$
Changing $y$ into $-y$ doesn't change the equation. This suggests the change of function :
$$Y(x)=y^2(x)$$
$$\left(3x-1\right)dx+\frac12 x^2\left(2+Y\right)dY=0$$
The equation is separable. Solvint it for $Y(x)$ is straightforward.